# Example of a series of functions that converges but does not converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to fully understand the concept of uniform convergence, and I would like to find an example that converges in regular way but not uniformly.

Please give me such a series of function preferrably with simple proof of convergence and of absence of uniform convergence. It would be a big plus if I could draw a graph of it and see what uniform convergence means on it.

Comment: For $\;x\in[0,1]\;,\;\;f_n(x):=x^n\;$ .

Comment: The basic idea is that with uniform convergence the limit function is continuous

Comment: @DonAntonio - that series doesn't seem convergent for $x=1$ ??

Comment: I was thinking of a *sequence* of functions, but now I see it says "series". Right, the series doesn't converge at $\;x=1\;$, the sequence does.

Comment: try $S_{n}(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} x^{n}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x) = 1$ if $n \le x < n+1$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise.

For every $x<0$ all the terms are zero; and for every $x \ge 0$ all the terms except one are zero, and exactly one term is $1$. So for fixed $x$ the series clearly converges. The sum is $f(x) = 0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x \ge 0$.

However, for every fixed $N$, the partial sum for $n \le N$ is zero for very large $x$ while the sum of the series is $1$. So the maximum difference between the sum of the infinite series and a finite partial sum is always 1, no matter how many terms you add in the partial sum. So the convergence is not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Take

> $$\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { x }^{ n } }{ n! }  } $$

in the interval $\left( 0,+\infty  \right) $ we know the sum of this serie is $S\left( x \right) ={ e }^{ x }$ and remainder of the sum ${ r }_{ n }\left( x \right) ={ e }^{ x }-\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { x }^{ k } }{ k! }  } $ ,but $$\underset { 0<x<+\infty  }{ sup } \left| { r }_{ n }\left( x \right)  \right| =+\infty $$ which shows doesn't converge uniformly